# Insertar en tabla campo, que sea el maximo de un registro de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, pdo, insert

tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo Cod_interno es nuemerico manual, y el campo id_categoria es AI, necesito para el proximo registro, que se seleccione el maximo de cod_interno, y se grabe en la tabla con el resto de los datos.... estoy usando algo así pero no me funciona:

```
INSERT INTO categorias (cod_interno, nombre, estado) VALUES ('SELECT max(cod_interno)+1 FROM categorias', :pasodato, :pasodato, :pasodato)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO categorias (cod_interno, nombre, estado)
SELECT cod_interno+1,nombre,estado
FROM categorias
WHERE cod_interno = (SELECT MAX(cod_interno) from categorias)
```